# Borrar un directorio en la carpeta opt - El directorio no esta vacío-

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, terminal

Necesito borrar ese directorio de la carpeta `/opt`.

Utilicé `$ rm android-studio` y la terminal arrojó:

> El directorio no esta vacío

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza:

```
$ rm -rf <la ruta del directorio>
```

Con `-f`, fuerzas a que se borre el directorio y `rm` no pregunta nada.

Con `-r`, `rm` borra recursivamente los directorios y su contenido.